# Clickhouse Client - Code: 62. DB::Exception: Empty query

Tags: docker-compose, clickhouse

I'm trying to run `clickhouse-server` and `clickhouse-client` services using **Docker** and **Docker Compose**. Based on [clickhouse docker-compose file](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) and [another compose sample](https://github.com/rongfengliang/clickhouse-docker-compose/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml), I created the services in my `docker-compose.yml` file as you can see below:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
    ch_server:
      container_name: myapp_ch_server
      image: yandex/clickhouse-server
      ports:
        - "8181:8123"
        - "9000:9000"
        - "9009:9009"
      ulimits:
        nproc: 65535
        nofile:
          soft: 262144
          hard: 262144
      volumes: 
        - ./ch_db_data:/var/lib/clickhouse/
        - ./ch_db_logs:/val/log/clickhouse-server/
      networks:
        - myapp-network

    ch_client:
      container_name: myapp_ch_client
      image: yandex/clickhouse-client
      command: ['--host', 'ch_server']
      networks:
        - myapp-network
```

When I run `docker-compose up` command, the following exception occurs from `clickhouse-client` service:

```sh
myapp_ch_client | Code: 62. DB::Exception: Empty query
myapp_ch_client exited with code 62
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just needs to pass the SQL-query in *command*-params:

```yaml
version: "2.4"

services:
  ch_server:
    container_name: myapp_ch_server
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9009:9009"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 262144
        hard: 262144
    volumes: 
      - ./ch_db_data:/var/lib/clickhouse/
      - ./ch_db_logs:/var/log/clickhouse-server/
    networks:
      - myapp-network
    healthcheck:
      test: wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider localhost:8123/ping || exit 1
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 16

  ch_client:
    container_name: myapp_ch_client
    image: yandex/clickhouse-client
    command: ['--host', 'ch_server', '--query', 'select * from system.functions order by name limit 4']
    networks:
      - myapp-network
    depends_on:
      ch_server:
        condition: service_healthy

networks:
    myapp-network:
```

---

It doesn't make sense to define *clickhouse-client* in *docker-compose*. *clickhouse-client* usually run outside of *docker-compose* file:

1. define *docker-compose* that defines **servers** (such as ClickHouse (nodes of cluster), Zookeeper, Apache Kafka, etc). For example, let's consider the config with one node of ClickHouse:

```yaml
version: "2.4"

services:
  ch_server:
    container_name: myapp_ch_server
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9009:9009"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 262144
        hard: 262144
    volumes: 
      - ./ch_db_data:/var/lib/clickhouse/
      - ./ch_db_logs:/var/log/clickhouse-server/
    networks:
      - myapp-network
    healthcheck:
      test: wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider localhost:8123/ping || exit 1
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 16

networks:
    myapp-network:
```

2. in the separate terminal run *clickhouse-client*

```sh
cd _folder_where_docker-compose_located

docker-compose exec ch_server clickhouse-client
```

Answer (score 1):

2021 version as this tutorial https://dev.to/titronium/clickhouse-server-in-1-minute-with-docker-4gf2

```
  clickhouse-client:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-client:latest
    depends_on:
      - clickhouse-server
    links:
      - clickhouse-server
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/sleep
    command:
      - infinity
```

the last line `command: - infinity` mean it will wait you there forever to connect

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have access to a ClickHouse client on the command line of the ClickHouse server.

You can easily connect to your server container and call

```
clickhuse-client
```